# Python flask server taking long time to boot

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, html

I have an odd problem at which when I run my code below in PyCharm or through the console (python script.py) the flask server takes an extremely long time to boot meaning when trying to access it it shows no content for a good few minutes.

```
import threading
from flask import render_template, request, logging, Flask, redirect

def setupFlask():
    appn = Flask(__name__)
    log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
    log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


    @appn.route('/')
    def page():
        return render_template('index.html')


    @appn.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
    def submit():
        token = request.form['ID']
        ID = token
        return redirect('/')

    appn.run()
a = threading.Thread(target=setupFlask)
a.daemon = True
a.start()
while True:
    pass
```

The odd thing is that when I run the same code above in the PyCharm debugger, the flask server takes about 5 seconds to boot, massively quicker than the few minutes it takes when run in the console. I would love that kind of speed when running the script normally and cant find a solution due to the problem fixing itself when in debugger!
This code snippet is part of a larger application, however I have adapted it to be run on its own and the same problem occurs.
I am not running in a virtualenv.
All help appreciated.

EDIT: The index.html document is very basic and only contains a few scripts and elements therefore I could not see it taking a long time to load.

Comment: This is strange. It should always be like 5s. How do you run i tin the console?

Comment: @Frynio Indeed... I run the function above in a thread and just do the normal "python script.py" in console. The same long boot time happens when running in PyCharm. I will edit the question slightly to make more sense.

Comment: Do you use virtualenv? And by the way, your imports are strange. I would always `from flask import Flask`, your code f.e doesn't work for me

Comment: Is your code sample the complete script or is it edited down? You're running the Flask app in a daemonic thread, suggesting there is more happening in the main thread, otherwise the process would exit after `a.start()`

Comment: After fixing imports I have the exact same behaviour @kristaps described

Comment: @Frynio I have edited code to be ran on its own. (sorry for odd imports, was in a rush!)  When I run the above in cmd I cannot access the server for a minute. I am not using a virtualenv. The code is a small function in a much larger app however when I run the above code, the same odd behaviour occurs. It makes it even weirder considering both of you have 5s boot times... This shows it is nothing to do with the other parts of the larger program. Again, when running this in PyCharm debugger, the boot time is normal at around 5s which is great.

Comment: @Frynio I am going to try and reinstall python and the modules in an old school attempt to fix seeing as you are not experiencing the same behaviour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with your `Flask` installation, but there's another one. You should not wait for your thread with a `while` loop. The better way is to [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) your thread, like this:

```
a = threading.Thread(target=setupFlask)
a.daemon = True
a.start()
a.join()
```